# parsing a controller to get methods and extra code/variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, codeigniter-2

I wrote a short script, which scans `application/controllers` and inserts the names of the controllers and methods into the DB. This is part of an ACL module, which lets me grant permissions to users.

I'm getting the methods with the following function -

```
$classname = ucfirst(substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.')));
$methods = get_class_methods($classname);
```

After processing I get the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [controller] => Inbox
            [method] => index
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [controller] => Inbox
            [method] => read
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [controller] => Inbox
            [method] => write
        )
)
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I add a new method to any controller, the unique ids, in the DB, no longer match my other table where I provide permission to the user based on those ids. Another problem is that some methods' names are not self explanatory, which makes it hard to understand the permissions when listing them from the DB.

I think the solution is to somehow parse the part of the controller where the name of the method is and then read some extra data (maybe from comments) so I can give unique IDs to each method, which will ensure that permissions stay linked to the user regardless the controllers' structures.

example

```
function read(){
//Desc:Reads a message.
//Unique method ID:2
...
}
```

and the inserted array would be something like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [desc] => nothing to do here
                [controller] => Inbox
                [method] => index
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [desc] => read a message
                [controller] => Inbox
                [method] => read
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [desc] => send a message
                [controller] => Inbox
                [method] => write
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the primary key for the ACL table a slug generated from the class name and method, instead of an integer?
That way it wont make a difference when you add new controllers/methods.

Very basic example of tables;
Actions

```
-----------------------------------
| id         | controller | method|
|---------------------------------|
| inbox_read | Inbox      | read  |
```

ACL

```
-----------------------
|user_id | acl_slug   |    
|--------|------------|
|  1     | inbox_read |
```

A little code example of how you may want to create the slug;

```
foreach ($method_array as $action) {
    $slug = strtolower(implode('_', $action));
}
```